# How can I get the cards to appear next to each other in a row to fill up the grid before starting a new row?

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am getting data from a table in my database and rendering it onto the screen as cards. However, the cards are all appearing on the left side of the screen in one long column instead of in 3s in a row as I would like them to appear.

My current code is here:

I've tried using `card-deck` which made it so that the cards were 3 in a row, but the cards were repeated (i.e. the data they held was repeated). I would like the data to not repeat, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `.row-sm-3` does but you don't even need a `.row`.

`.card-deck` has `flex` and will act similarly to a Bootstrap `.row`. Your spacing (e.g., `col-lg-3`, `.col-md-6`) should be used on each `.card`. See the snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ class.class_name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{class.teacher_id.username }}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go To</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ class.class_name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{class.teacher_id.username }}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go To</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ class.class_name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{class.teacher_id.username }}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go To</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ class.class_name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{class.teacher_id.username }}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go To</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ class.class_name}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{class.teacher_id.username }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go To</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

```html
<div class="container">
  {% for class in all_classes %}
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ class.class_name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{class.teacher_id.username }}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go To</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou but my problem is that I need to be able to loop through the database table and display the data on the screen as cards. I can't write the code for the cards for each set of data because that would be tedious. Is there a way that I can loop through my database and display the cards on the screen in rows without using the deck format?

Comment: @monkey_man you'll have to elaborate a bit more. I assumed you already had this part figured out as it wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @monkey_man see edits. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I've tried your edit code but that's yielding the same results I've had. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) in bootstrap you need to follow the structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Item 1</div>
    <div class="col">Item 2</div>
    <div class="col">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

However, you use `row-sm-3`, which does not work. You need to change it to just `row`.

Also, you are missing a `</div>` closing tag in your example, but I guess that was a copy-paste mistake.